# The mask Morokei glitched off my companion

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

My companion had the mask equipped and when he joined the blades, he changed his outfit. So I looked at his inventory to take the mask back, but he didn't have it anymore. I tried everything, but I think the mask glitched off. It's either recover the saved data or start over since I can't progress through the game anymore.

Comment: How is the mask stopping your progress?

Comment: wait a minute!!! DID YOU KILL PAARTHURNAX?

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known bug](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Morokei_(Mask)#Bugs):

> If any mask is given to any follower, over time it may disappear from their inventory.

So, as you stated, your options are limited to continuing from an earlier save point, or start over.

The good news is, this is not plot essential; it is only required in order to gain the [Konahrik](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Konahrik_(Mask)) mask, so you can continue on with the game.

Comment: Maybe good to add that additionally, you can use `Player.additem 61C8B "1"` to 'return' it to your own inventory.

Comment: @Joachim the OP is on the PS3, so they don't have access to console commands.

Comment: Ah, apologies. I was skimming over it too fast..

Comment: Still useful for anybody else who encounters this post when googling with a similar problem, so totally would make sense to make it a part of the answer.